# How to get the Diffrence between two Dates as nDays n Minutes n Seconds

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have two date values.

1. `Date now=new Date();`
2. Another `date` variable.

I want to find out the difference bet them in xxxDays XXXHours XXMin XXXSeconds.How can I achieve this.

```
Date now=new Date();  
Date date2="2013-07-04 18:06:27"; //(I will get this from a DB).  
String/Date dateDiff=date2.getTime()-now.getTime();
```

Some thing like this

Comment: What about start writing some code ?

Comment: Just search before your post, There are lot more answer for this on internet. mean while can you please post your code???

Comment: Use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), which is suggested to every other question on this topic...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating the Difference Between Two Java Date Instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference you get from two dates is in miliseconds, so your code should look something like this:

```
var difference = date1 - date2;
var days = difference / (1000*60*60*24);
var hours = (difference - days*1000*60*60*24) / (1000*60*60);
var minutes = (difference - days*1000*60*60*24 - hours*1000*60*60) / (1000*60)
var seconds = (difference - days*1000*60*60*24 - hours*1000*60*60 - minutes*1000*60)/ 1000
```

Comment: instead of using those ugly multiplications you should use `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit`

Answer (score 0):

With `java.util.date`:

```
int diffInDays = (int)((newDate.getTime() - oldDate.getTime()) / (1000*60*60*24))
```

Note that this works with UTC dates.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using [`TimeUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html)

```
final SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
final Date old = fmt.parse("10/7/2013 10:10");
final Date now = fmt.parse("12/7/2013 12:12");

long dif = now.getTime() - old.getTime();
final long days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(dif);
dif -= TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(days);
final long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(dif);
dif -= TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hours);
long mins = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(dif);

System.out.format("%d days, %d hours, %d mins\n", days, hours, mins);
```

Which correctly prints:

```
2 days, 2 hours, 2 mins
```